# How to submit the value of the selected link when using Ajax Form?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

The name of the selected link is the value that needs to be submitted to the controller from an Ajax form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

used Ajax.ActionLinks

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like so using mootools where the links you want to capture clicks on have the class 'selectedLinks':

```
var links = $$('a.selectedLinks');
for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++){
    links.addEvent('click', function(){
       var myRequest = new Request({method: 'get', url: 'yourRequestHandler.php'});
       myRequest.send('name=' + this.getProperty('name'));
       return false;
    });
}
```